# How should I encode the input which are 5 cards from a deck of 52 cards?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, ai-design, data-preprocessing

How should I design my input layer for the following classification problem?

> **Input**: 5 cards (from a deck of 52 cards) in a card game;
>
> **Output**: some classification using a neural network

How should I model the input layer?

**Option A**: 5 one-hot encodings for the 5 cards, i.e. 5 one-hot vectors of length 52 = 260 input vector. For example

```
[
[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,...],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,...],
[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,...],
[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,...],
[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,...]
]
```

**Option B**: 5 hot encoding encompassing all 5 cards in one 52 element vector

```
[1,0,1,0,1,1,1,...]
```

What are the disadvantages between A and B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how your game is played. Is there any meaning assigned to the order of cards, or are all 5 played simultaneously? If order matters, use 5 one-hot vectors so you can choose how to order them, otherwise use a single 5-hot input vector. I would also add that if **temporal** order matters, you could also use a **recurrent** net with a 52-element input and feed the five one-hot vectors one after another.